# Can't call functions from param powershell

Tags: powershell

I have some functions in a powershell script that I am trying to execute using params.
I have did this before for other powershell scripts and it worked perfectly but now, when I try to run any of my functions I get this:

`intermedia_pwsh_functions.ps1 -Add-im_Email`

```
InvalidOperation: /home/tech/scripts/Alloy_automate/intermedia_pwsh_functions.ps1:80:3
Line |
  80 |  & $command
     |    ~~~~~~~~
     | The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a
     | CommandInfo object.
```

Here is my code:

```
param (
    $command,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'license')]
    $imcid,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'email')]
    $eoptenantID,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'email')]
    $emailresult,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'email')]
    $empw,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'email')]
    $emname,
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'email')]
)

function Add-im_Email {
    #creates AD and email account
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString "RMLword3$" -AsPlainText -Force
    $emailpass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "TPPass1!" -AsPlainText -Force
    $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("rockomodernlife@conglomo.com", $password)
    $ses = New-PSSession -Name "rockomodernlife@conglomo.com" -ConnectionUri https://exchange.intermedia.net/powershell -ConfigurationName Hosting.PowerShell -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic
    Invoke-Command -Session $ses -ScriptBlock {Set-ConnectionSettings -CredentialType "User" -Credential $Using:Cred -AccountID "456433"}
    Invoke-Command -Session $ses -ScriptBlock {New-User -DisplayName "pwsh test" -UserPrincipalName "rugrats@conglomo.com" -Password $Using:emailpass | Enable-ExchangeMailbox -Force -Confirm:$false }
    exit
}
# & $CommandName @Arguments
& $command
```

Comment: Remove the `-` in front of `Add-im_email`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this so I tried both and it failed both times. I first tried removing `-` from the command like so `intermedia_pwsh_functions.ps1 Add-in_email` and that failed. I then tried to remove `-` from the actual function like so: `function Addin_email` then tried to run the script but I still got the same error regarding scriptblock error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we get to the `$command` argument, there's something we need to fix.

You can only have *one* `[CmdletBinding]` attribute - and it's applied to the `param(...)` block as a whole - then you can use `[Parameter]` attributes on the individual parameter declarations to assign them to a parameter set:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'email')]
param (
    $command,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'license')]
    $imcid,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'email')]
    $eoptenantID,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'email')]
    $emailresult,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'email')]
    $empw,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'email')]
    $emname,
)

<# function definition(s) go here#>

& $command
```

---

To pass the function name `Add-im_Email` as an argument to the `$command` parameter, invoke your script like this:

```
intermedia_pwsh_functions.ps1 -command Add-im_Email
```

Comment: When I first tried it, it didn't work for me. however I was using the full path in the powershell interpreter. The moment I did `.\intermedia_pwsh_functions.ps1 -command Add-im_Email` instead it worked. (This was ofcourse after I changed my params to your suggestion.) Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too early. It worked as `.\intermedia_pwsh_functions.ps1 -command Add-im_Email`. but if I add any other params after, it doesn't work. such as '.\intermedia_pwsh_functions.ps1 -command Add-im_Email -empw "somepassword"`. I will make a new question about it.